# Create a shared copy and paste menu for my grids

Tags: vb.net, contextmenu

I have 20 or so grids in my application suite. I'd like to create a global copy/paste context menu which I can bind to every single grid rather than code in each form.

I am unsure what is the best way to achieve this, I have started to create a class with my menu in it, but get stuck at the point of adding the actual menu options. For example I know I'll need to call a "copy" event, but I also know I'll need to tell it what I am copying, and I cannot see how that is done in vb.net when you can only add the address of a method minus parameters.

e.g.

```
.MenuItems.Add("Copy Cell", New System.EventHandler(AddressOf CopyCell))
```

Obviously I want "CopyCell" to only be coded in one place as well, rather than repeated in each form. I will always be copying the same object (SelectedCellCollection).

I am not sure how to make the menu have an event with parameters, or how to make it "know" that I want to always copy the selected items. I'm aware that I'd have to do some coding in the form but just trying to work out the way to minimize it.

Answer (score 0):

I have created my own context menu class (via inheritance) with specific copy and paste functionality / options tailored to the grid I am using. It works fine and only needs one line of code per form/grid to activate.